# Why does not the @Id annotation give me a unique index

Tags: spring-data-mongodb

Spring Boot 2.3.4

org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web

org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb

MongoDB 4.2.8

I have the following class:

```
@TypeAlias("RefreshToken")
@Document("refresh_token")
@CompoundIndex(name = "organization_user", def = "{'organizationId' : 1, 'userId': 1}")
data class RefreshToken(

    @Id
    val token: String,
    val organizationId: UUID,
    val userId: UUID,
    val expiry: Date
)
```

A unique index/constraint on the `token` field is not created. I'm getting duplicates for some reason.

The indices being created are these:

[image]

Comment: There is a unique index on the _id field which is in your case the token property. Can you post the query where you get duplicates. Is your mongodb setup sharded?

Comment: The following query returns duplicates: 

{ 'token' : ?1 }

Comment: the name of the property at your mongodb is not 'token' but '_id''. So you have to query for { '_id': ?1 }. Every mongodb document must have a _id field. You just mark the token propery in your java class as @Id property and spring-data-mongodb maps this to the _id field.

Comment: So what you are saying is that adding @Id to the token does not make the token field the unique ID in MongoDB. Whats the point with the Id annotation if there is an _id field we have to use anyway?

Comment: no, the token field is the _id field on the database side. As said: spring just maps your token property to the _id field. The @Id annotation marks the token property as the _id field. Take a look at the docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#mongo-template.id-handling

Comment: Well how can the same value in the token field then result in different values in _id?